# In Java how does method overloading is typically implemented

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I'm writing a parser using `ANTLR4` which accepts some function expression with arguments. Arguments can be `String`, `int`, `double`, and the function expression itself.

The thing is I would like to support functions with different signatures, but with the same name (i.e. overloading). So the parser can successfully parse the following expressions:

```
sum(hash('some_string'), 2, 3)
```

and

```
sum(hash('some_string'), 2)
```

I would not like to accept var-args, but only with 2 and 3 parameters. Can someone get me an idea of how to implement overloading. In particularly, how does `javac` implement it?

Comment: You already did it. What is the issue here ?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Okay, how can I know the exact overloaded function I need to call? Support some sort of overloaded table?

Comment: You have to declare a function for every parameters cardinality and/or combination parameters, by type, you need.
The compiler will select for you the rigth one based on input.

Comment: The signature of a function is based on name and parameters number and type. At compile time the right one will be selected. The overload term is just syntactic sugar; the compiler does not care of how the function is called in the code.

Comment: The name of the function to call **is the signature** and vice versa.  Don't think of your example as one function called `sum` with two overloadings; 
think instead in terms of two entirely different functions, called `sum_int_int` and `sum_int_int_int`.

Comment: If you want an essential but thorough intro to how languages work I can suggest you an (e)book: [Programming Languages, principles and paradigms](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9781848829138). I had the chance to follow a course held by one of the authors and it was enlightening! (I'm fond with this book)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will know which overloaded method the code requires based on what data types were passed as parameters. Example overloading of your **sum()** method

```
public String sum(String hashString, int intValue, double dblValue) {
    // method code here....
    return result;
}

public String sum(String hashString, double dblValue, int intValue) {
    // method code here....
    return result;
}

public String sum(String hashString, int intValue) {
    // method code here....
    return result;
}

public String sum(String hashString, double dblValue) {
    // method code here....
    return result;
}

public String sum(String hashString, int... intValue) {
    // intValue is optional, one or more can be supplied or
    // an array of int's can be supplied. As examples....

    int intParam = 0;
    if (intValue.length > 0) {
        intParam = intValue[0];  
    }
    // method code here....

    //        OR (remove the above)

    int intParam1 = 0, intParam2 = 0;
    if (intValue.length > 0) {
        if (intValue.length >= 1) { intParam1 = intValue[0]; }
        if (intValue.length >= 2) { intParam2 = intValue[1]; }
    }
    // method code here....

    //        OR (remove the above)

    for (int i = 0; i < intValue.length; i++) {
        int intParam = intValue[i];
        // method code here....
    }

    //        OR (remove the above)

    // whatever other way you want to handle the
    // supplied optional arguments.
    // Method code here....
    return result;
}

public String sum(String hashString, double... dblValue) {
    // dblValue is optional, one or more can be supplied or
    // an array of double's can be supplied. 
    // method code here....
    return result;
}

etc., etc....
```